# Get windows crash dialogue out of the way of a crashing process

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch, crash

**TL;DR:**

Windows 7 pro displays a dialogue that hangs a crashing process, preventing it from closing. I need windows to just let the process die. I would prefer to make this rule specific to one the executable, but disabling this behavior system-wide would be acceptable.

**Long version:**

I have a server-side application that is, shall we say, particular about its execution environment. It only runs on windows 7 pro. So I give it a tiny VM and all is good, for a while.

About once a week, it crashes (usually page fault). Coming from a unix background, the solution is easy enough, just stick it in a loop. So I have a batch file:

`:loop
the_process.exe
goto loop`

However, when the process crashes, windows stalls the process and displays a dialogue saying the process has crashed with a few options. The loop does not, well, loop until someone clicks "close the program" (or anything else for that matter). I want windows to get it's user-friendliness out of the way so the batch file can do its job.

I would prefer the rule applies just to the one exe or things run from the batch file, but disabling it system-wide would also be acceptable.

This process is legacy code that we will be replacing soon (with unix version), but we need it to run consistently on the VM for now.

As one would expect, everything I can find on the net is about attaching a debugger or finding a dump file.

Edit: screenshot of error:

[image: screenshot of crash dialogue]

Comment: Are you wanting to disable Windows Error Reporting (WER)?  I assume you get an event in the Application event log?  Can you provide a screenshot of the message.  https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-disable-error-reporting-windows-7.htm was the first page when Google for disable WER.

Comment: Yes, there's an event in the log. That's how I know it's page faulting ;) I did try that, but the problem dialog was replaced with another dialogue say the program has crashed with only a "OK" button, but it still hangs the process until someone wakes up and hits the button. I will submit a screenshot the next time it happens if the problem is still not resolved.

Comment: @HelpingHand added screenshot as requested.